# What is this Map Algebra expression performing in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, spatial-analyst, map-algebra

I was given a model my someone else, and am trying to decipher exactly what they are doing.

There is a step in the model which has the following expression:

```
SetNull("%Raster1%"<0,"%Raster 1%")
```

Is it taking all values of 0 and setting them to null?

What is happening in the second portion of the condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Set Null](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/set-null.htm) tool takes the following parameters:

`SetNull (in_conditional_raster, in_false_raster_or_constant, {where_clause})`

which are described in the tool's documentation as follows:

> - `in_conditional_raster`: Input raster representing the true or false result of the desired condition. It can be of integer or floating
>     point type.
> - `in_false_raster_or_constant`: The input whose values will be used as the output cell values if the condition is false. It can be an
>     integer or a floating point raster, or a constant value.
> - `{where_clause}` (optional): A logical expression that determines which of the input cells are to be true or false. The expression
>     follows the general form of an SQL expression. An example of a
>     where_clause is "VALUE > 100".

What the statment is doing is setting to Null all the pixels that satisfy the `"%Raster1%"<0` condition and leaving intact those pixels that do not satisfy the condition, which equals to the same raster, hence being the second parameter just the raster (*i.e.* `"%Raster1%"`).